# distinct on Union of queries in Zend

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I want to get 'DISTINCT(ITEMS)' from the two sub queries, but it gives me an error. 
Also cannot apply distinct to each query because the tables are different.

```
 $sql1 = $zdb->select()
        ->from($table1, array('id','items'))
        ->where('data    = ?', $arrData['data']);
    $sql2 = $zdb->select()
        ->from($table2, array('id','items'))
        ->where('data    = ?', $arrData['data']);
    $select = $zdb->select('DISTINCT(items)')->union(array($sql1, $sql2));
```

Pls help me thanks in advance

Comment: Did you really need to use CAPs?

Comment: also tried without caps $zdb->select('distinct(items)')->union(array($sql1, $sql2)); like this but doesn't work

Comment: I was talking about you using Caps lock to ask a question:D

Comment: Are you using Zend framework 2 or 1

Comment: Can you print the final query?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you can try this:

```
$select = $zdb->select()->distinct()->union(array($sql1, $sql2));
```

Answer (score 0):

As second parameter you can pass the Zend_Db_Select::SQL_UNION or Zend_Db_Select::SQL_UNION_ALL constants to specify which type of union you want to perform.